# Can large power stations which are not running can be used for power factor improvement of national grid. How?

Tags: power-factor-correction

My friend told me that the large power stations which are not running can be used for power factor improvement of  national grid. I wonder how it can be done? If true, can these stations charge for this service?

Comment: We welcome new users. But this is beyond engineering design.

Comment: ask your friend

Answer (score 2):

Most large power stations use synchronous machines, attached to the shaft of a prime mover (like a steam turbine or hydro turbine).

There is an excitation current applied to the rotor of these machines, which controls the vector angle between voltage and current.

What you've been told about is a situation where the machine is spinning but not being 'pushed' by the prime mover. Instead the machine is excited in such a way as to produce (or sink) reactive power, which effectively changes the power factor.

I am sure that in energy markets, there will some business benefit to this, assuming there is demand for it.